# How do I start Deluge in the background?

Tags: boot, services, bittorrent, deluge

Basically I have Deluge all setup for my account with Transdroid and the WebUI and everything, however, what I would really like, is for it to start the moment the computer does so that no matter who logs in, my downloads continue. Furthermore, I don't want other users to be able to see it when they log in, not in the taskbar or in the notification area. What would be ideal would be to have it as a service which I could control through the Deluge GUI. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deluge has a daemon too. I haven't tried deluge since I started using transmission, and I've never tried deluge's daemon, but I know it has one. You might have to install the daemon (deluged) separately. It may be as easy as putting the following line in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
sudo -u yourusername deluged
```

but read the manual page for deluged first (`man deluged`). You might have to tell it to use the same configuration as the gui version, and it may have a separate init or upstart script, in which case you'll want to edit those instead of `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Thanks, I pulled an all nighter, but I solved it, largely thanks to your comment.

Comment: Care to share with us how you did it? :)

Answer (score 2):

You are needing to run **deluged**, this is the Deluge daemon.

Two options for running at startup is either by [InitScript](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu) or simply add deluged to Startup Applications.

To connect to deluged you need to disable 'classic mode' in deluge/deluge-gtk then use the connection manager to connect to the localhost deluged.

Also see Deluge [forum](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/) and wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an article on the Deluge website that tells you how to do it very easily (I needed to redo it after I reinstalled). I just followed this word for word and it seems to work. Remember to **change the deluged user**.

- [for Initd](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/DebianUbuntuInitd) (Debian and old Ubuntu)
- [for Upstart](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/Upstart) (more current Ubuntu)

  - (Note that you have to modify the `.conf` file to say `env uid=yourusername`)

Answer (score 1):

Old question but the answers did not work/not appropriate for me so added my scenario (16.04 , systemd)

For Systemd (Seemingly 15.04+, definitely 16.04):

Tested as working, guest user cannot login to deluge, requires auth at localhost. They can see the service is running, but that should be about it, all depends on users privileges.

**As seen here: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/systemd**

This assumes deluge is your username and groupname, and you setup as per normal guide. Personally I use a different username etc.

Create the file /etc/systemd/system/deluged.service containing the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon
Documentation=man:deluged
After=network-online.target
[Service]
Type=simple
User=deluge
Group=deluge
UMask=007
ExecStart=/usr/bin/deluged -d
Restart=on-failure
# Time to wait before forcefully stopped.
TimeoutStopSec=300
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You may wish to modify the above umask as it applies to any files downloaded by deluged.

- 007 grants full access to the user and members of the group deluged
  is running as (in this case deluge) and prevents access from all
  other accounts.
- 022 grants full access to the user deluged is running as and only
  read access to other accounts.
- 002 grants full access to the user and group deluged is running as
  and only read access to other accounts.
- 000 grants full access to all accounts.

Refer to ​Wikipedia for details of possible values and their effects. Deluged must be stopped and started instead of just restarted after changes. If you enable logging, the umasks specified here also affect the permissions of newly created logs.

Now enable it to start up on boot, start the service and verify it is running:

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/deluged.service
sudo systemctl start deluged
sudo systemctl status deluged
```